# container-puppet-rabbitmq doesn't work when deploying overcloud with tripleo

Tags: openstack, rabbitmq, tripleo

I been trying install openstack overcloud with tripleo
but not work container-puppet-rabbitmq container.

===environment===

Hypervisor : Vmware

VM#1 : Undercloud

VM#2 : Overcloud_Controller

VM#3 : Overcloud_Compute

OS : Centos stream 8

Openstack Version : Wallaby

===deploy logs===

2023-05-22 17:29:06.370739 | 000c29c7-41d9-74b1-3404-00000000354f |       TASK | Create containers managed by Podman for /var/lib/tripleo-config/container-puppet-config/step_1
2023-05-22 17:29:24.978885 |                                      |    WARNING | **ERROR: Can't run container container-puppet-rabbitmq**
stderr: + /usr/bin/puppet apply --summarize --detailed-exitcodes --color=false --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/openstack-puppet/modules --tags '"file,file_line,concat,augeas,cron,file,file_line"' /etc/config.pp

- logger -s -t puppet-user
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user: Warning: /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml: Use of 'hiera.yaml' version 3 is deprecated. It should be converted to version 5
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user:    (file: /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml)
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user: Warning: Undefined variable '::deploy_config_name';
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user:    (file & line not available)
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user: Warning: The function 'hiera' is deprecated in favor of using 'lookup'. See https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.6/deprecated_language.html
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user:    (file & line not available)
  **<13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user: Error: Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'stack_action'**
- rc=1
- '[' false = false ']'
- set +x
  2023-05-22 17:29:24.979553 | 000c29c7-41d9-74b1-3404-00000000354f |      FATAL | Create containers managed by Podman for /var/lib/tripleo-config/container-puppet-config/step_1 | inje-ctrl01 | error={"changed": false, "msg": "Failed containers: container-puppet-rabbitmq"}
  2023-05-22 17:29:24.979886 | 000c29c7-41d9-74b1-3404-00000000354f |     TIMING | tripleo_container_manage : Create containers managed by Podman for /var/lib/tripleo-config/container-puppet-config/step_1 | inje-ctrl01 | 0:05:46.518880 | 18.61s

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************

inje-cn01                  : ok=274  changed=133  unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=162  rescued=0    ignored=1

inje-ctrl01                : ok=287  changed=147  unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=165  rescued=0    ignored=1

localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0

undercloud                 : ok=21   changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=1

===Controller Container logs===

[root@inje-ctrl01 ~]# podman logs container-puppet-rabbitmq
include ::tripleo::packages
['Rabbitmq_policy', 'Rabbitmq_user'].each |String $val| { noop_resource($val) }
include tripleo::profile::pacemaker::rabbitmq_bundle
Running puppet

- /usr/bin/puppet apply --summarize --detailed-exitcodes --color=false --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/openstack-puppet/modules --tags '"file,file_line,concat,augeas,cron,file,file_line"' /etc/config.pp
- logger -s -t puppet-user
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user: Warning: /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml: Use of 'hiera.yaml' version 3 is deprecated. It should be converted to version 5
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user:    (file: /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml)
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user: Warning: Undefined variable '::deploy_config_name';
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user:    (file & line not available)
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user: Warning: The function 'hiera' is deprecated in favor of using 'lookup'. See https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.6/deprecated_language.html
  <13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user:    (file & line not available)
  **<13>May 22 17:29:22 puppet-user: Error: Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'stack_action'**
- rc=1
- '[' false = false ']'
- set +x

====puppet/hiera verion===

[root@inje-ctrl01 ~]# puppet --version

7.6.1

[root@inje-ctrl01 ~]#  hiera --version

3.6.0

How can i fixed it?

thank you for your help.